# Fourier transform unitary operator

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to understand why there is a continous extenstion of $\mathcal{F}_0f$ to a unitary operator in $L^2$. So let $\mathcal{F}_0f: S(\mathbb{R}^m) \to S(\mathbb{R}^m).$ This is a bijective Operator.

I can show that for $f,g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ the operator is isometric.

So injectivity follows from isometry, right?

Then I have the claim range($\mathcal{F})=\overline{range \mathcal{F}_0}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^m)$. Why is this true and where can i see this? And is it right that i can follow the surjectivity from this?

Comment: For $u \in L^2$ take $u_n \to u, u_n \in S$, $\|F u_n\| =\|u_n\|$ so $Fu = \lim_{n \to \infty} Fu_n$ converges and $\|Fu\| = \|u\|$

Comment: And can you tell me something about $range(\mathcal{F})=\overline{range( \mathcal{F}_0)}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^m)$?